# Somar em vez de concatenar número ao valor de um input

Tags: javascript

Não sei se me fiz entender, mas no código javascript abaixo, quero que cada vez que eu clicar no botão, ocorra uma soma, porém só estou conseguindo concatenar. Obrigado!

```js
function somar(){
    document.getElementById("valorSomado").value += 80;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="somar();">Somar</button>

<input type="text" id="valorSomado">
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O valor do input é lido como *String*, tens de converter em *Number* para adicionar em vez de concatenar.

Podes fazer assim:

```
var somar = (function(el) {
    return function() {
        el.value = Number(el.value) + 80;
    }
})(document.getElementById("valorSomado"));
```

**jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/co29oovs/**

ou usando o espaço global:

```
var somado = document.getElementById("valorSomado");
function somar() {
    somado.value = Number(somado.value) + 80;
}
```

Comment: Funcionou, muito obrigado!

Comment: Uma dica legal é usar o typeof para verificar o tipo da variável.

Comment: @MauroAlexandre Neste caso não precisa, porque o *value* do campo vai sempre ser string.

Comment: @FreneticFx ótimo! Se quiseres podes clicar e marcar a resposta como "aceite".